# Tiny python add skip blank line rule, Antlr4

Tags: python, antlr4, blank-line

I am using https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/tiny-python/tiny-grammar-without-actions/Python3.g4

grammar ,and I want to add a rule to skip blank line( line: 6)

```
a = 0
b = 2
sum = 0
if b > a:
    i = b

    sum += i
print(sum)
```

I have test this code ,but not work for me

```
WS:[ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

```
line 8:4     : missing NEWLINE at 'sum'
```

Edit:

```
ss = 4
if 3>1:
    ss = 3
    #dddd
    ss = 4
```

when i add above code ,it will report another error

```
line 4:9 : extraneous input '\n ' expecting {'break', 'continue', 'if', 'while', 'for', 'print', 'def', 'return', NAME, '(', DEDENT}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANTLR4 skips empty line only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519842/antlr4-skips-empty-line-only)

Comment: As i add blank line in if statement，it will throw Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `WS:[ \t\r\n]+ '\n'-> skip;`, you're essentially removing (skipping) the new line after `i = b` and the empty line after it:

```
i = b

sum += i
```

resulting in this:

```
i = b sum += i
```

which is no good: you need a new line after `i = b`.

Instead of skipping empty lines, you could try to let empty lines be a part of your `NEWLINE` token. So instead of doing:

```
NEWLINE
 : ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' ) SPACES?
 ;
```

you'd do:

```
NEWLINE
 : ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' ) (SPACES? ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' ))* SPACES?
 ;
```

which will make sure the new line after `i = b` is not removed.

Comment: I have another problem，and i have editor my question