# NoViableAltException in Antlr4.3 grammar

Tags: c#, .net, antlr4

## Problem

I just started using ANTLR (4.3 for .NET) and after debugging for quite a while, I have to surrender. I get a `NoViableAltException` in the last 4 lines - but I really have no idea how to fix it ...

So you have any hints for me?

## Supposed Behavior

The generated parser is supposed to parse strings like `Hello {User.Name}!` or `Hello {{ {User.Name("}")} }}!` where `User.Name` and `User.Name("}")` are expected to derive from the `expression` rule and everything else from `plainString`. However, I was not yet able to test it ...

## Grammar

```
grammar PatternString;

@namespace{PatternStringParser.AntlrGenerated}

patternString:            (plainString | expressionString)+;

plainString:              (PLAINSTRINGLITERAL | '""' | '{{' | '}}' )+;

expressionString:        '{' expression* '}';

expression:               BALANCEDSTRINGLITERAL+
                          | '(' expression ')'
                          | '[' expression ']'
                          | '{' expression '}'
                          | '"' string '"'
                          | '\'' character '\'';

string:                   (STRINGLITERAL | '\\"')+;

character:                (CHARACTERLITERAL | '\'' )+;

PLAINSTRINGLITERAL:      ~[\"\{\}];      // <= NoViableAltException
BALANCEDSTRINGLITERAL:   ~[\"\{\(\[\'];  // <= NoViableAltException
CHARACTERLITERAL:        ~[\'];          // <= NoViableAltException
STRINGLITERAL:           ~[\"];          // <= NoViableAltException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze this kind of problem, dump the token stream to see what the lexer is actually doing.  To dump the tokens, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197727/antlr-4-5-parser-error-during-runtime/29198883#29198883) - it is in Java, but the C# implementation should be quite similar.

Comment: Already fixed it randomly, but thank you for your answer that will make it easier the next time!