# AnTLR4 strange behavior in precedence

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have a very simple test grammar as following:

```
grammar Test;

statement: expression EOF;

expression
    :   Identifier
        |   expression binary_op expression
        |   expression assignment_operator expression
        |   expression '.' Identifier 
    ;

binary_op: '+';
assignment_operator : '='  ;

Identifier : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
WS : [ \n\r\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

With this version of the grammar I got the expected behavior if I write the following code:

```
b.x + b.y
```

I get a tree as `(+ (. b x) (. b y))`

However, if I replace `expression binary_op expression` by `expression '+' expression` I get a very different tree: `(. (+ (. b x) b) y)`

Is there any explanation for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the precendence using something like this:

```
expr  : expr2 (assignment_operator expr3)?  # Equals
expr2 : expr1 (binary_op expr2)?            # Add
expr1 : Identifier | 
        expr1 . Identifier
      ;
```

This removes all ambiguity on operator precendence.

Answer (score 0):

Literals in the parser can confuse matters.  Check and fix the errors/warnings reported in generating the parser.  Likely need to move the literals from parser rules to lexer rules.

You can verify that the lexer is operating as intended by [dumping the token stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197727/antlr-4-5-parser-error-during-runtime/29198883#29198883).  That will provide a clear basis for understanding the path that the parser is taking.

**Update**

Neither of the parse tree representations you list look proper for an Antlr4 parse tree. Nonetheless, tried both variants of your grammar and I consistently get:

Token dump:

```
Identifier: [@0,0:0='b',<4>,1:0]
Dot: [@1,1:1='.',<3>,1:1]
Identifier: [@2,2:2='x',<4>,1:2]
null: [@4,4:4='+',<1>,1:4]
Identifier: [@6,6:6='b',<4>,1:6]
Dot: [@7,7:7='.',<3>,1:7]
Identifier: [@8,8:8='y',<4>,1:8]
```

Tree dump:

```
(statement (expression (expression (expression (expression b) . x) + (expression b)) . y) <EOF>)
```

using

```
ParseTree tree = parser.statement();
System.out.print(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

The `null`s in this particular token dump are because the symbols are first defined in the parser.

Comment: Doesn't make difference moving the literals from parser rules to lexer rules. I tested. :)