# Lambda expression in ANTLR mismatched input

Tags: lambda, antlr, antlr4, lambda-calculus

i want to implement a parser for lambda expressions. But i get "mismatched input ' ' expecting ')' " error for that input: (\x.x x) (\x.x x) , dont know why...

I have a grammar:

```
grammar Lambda;


lambda_expression : VARIABLE
                 | '\\' VARIABLE '.' lambda_expression
                 | ('(' lambda_expression ')')+
                 | EOF
; 

VARIABLE : 'x' | 'y' | 'z' | 'v' | 'w'
 ;                

WS : (' ')+  -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

and this is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("(\\x.x x) (\\x.x x)");
        LambdaLexer lex = new LambdaLexer(input) ;
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        LambdaParser parser = new LambdaParser(tokens);
        parser.lambda_expression();

        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
        LambdaParser.Lambda_expressionContext tree = parser.lambda_expression();
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

    }
```

I'm using antlr4-4.1-complete.jar

Answer (score 1):

The recursion on `lambda_expression` of alt3 `(` -> alt2 `\x.` -> alt1 `x` matches `(\x.x`, leaving the parser wanting to then complete the match of alt3 with a `)`.

Changing alt2 to

```
    | '\\' VARIABLE ( '.' lambda_expression )+ lambda_expression
```

might be the solution, depending on whether it actually reflects your allowed lambda syntax.

Comment: but i think there is an issue with the WS parsing, isn't? 'cause the lexer dont recognize it, however i defined WS

Comment: No. The error message shows what is next in the actual input character stream, not the next token. If there is a question about what the lexer is doing, [dump the token stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197727/antlr-4-5-parser-error-during-runtime/29198883#29198883). The space token will be correctly marked as hidden.