# ANTLR: Parse a date within a quote string

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a problem figuring out how to parse a date in my grammar.

The thing is that it shares its definition with a String, but according to the Antlr 4 documentation, it should follow the precedence by looking at the order of declaration.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar formula;


/* entry point */
parse: expr EOF;

expr
    : value                                  # argumentArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=('*'|'/'|'%') r=expr   # multdivArithmeticExpr // TODO: test the % operator
    | l=expr operator=('+'|'-') r=expr       # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | '-' expr                               # minusArithmeticExpr
    | FUNCTION_NAME '(' (expr ( ','  expr )* ) ? ')'# functionExpr
    | '(' expr ')'                           # parensArithmeticExpr
    ;

value
    : number
    | variable
    | date
    | string
    | bool;

/* Atomes */

bool
    : BOOL
    ;

variable
    : '[' (~(']') | ' ')* ']'
    ;

date
    : DQUOTE date_format DQUOTE
    | QUOTE date_format QUOTE
    ;

date_format
    : year=INT '-' month=INT '-' day=INT (hour=INT ':' minutes=INT ':' seconds=INT)?
    ;

string
    : STRING_LITERAL
    ;


number
    : ('+'|'-')? NUMERIC_LITERAL
    ;


/* lexemes de base */

QUOTE   : '\'';
DQUOTE  : '"';
MINUS   : '-';
COLON   : ':';
DOT     : '.';
PIPE    : '|';
BOOL    : T R U E | F A L S E;

FUNCTION_NAME: IDENTIFIER ;

IDENTIFIER
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* // TODO: do we more chars in this set?
 ;

NUMERIC_LITERAL
 : DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT* )? ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )? // ex: 0.05e3
 | '.' DIGIT+ ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )? // ex: .05e3
 ;

INT: DIGIT+;

STRING_LITERAL
    :  '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
    |  '"' ( ~'"' | '""' )* '"'
    ;

WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;

UNEXPECTED_CHAR: . ;

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');
```

The important part here is this:

```
value
    : number
    | variable
    | date
    | string
    | bool;

date
    : DQUOTE date_format DQUOTE
    | QUOTE date_format QUOTE
    ;

date_format
    : year=INT '-' month=INT '-' day=INT (hour=INT ':' minutes=INT ':' seconds=INT)?
    ;
```

My grammar expects these things:

- `"a quoted string"` -> gives a `string`
- `"2015-03 TOTOTo"` -> gives a `string` because the date format doesn't match.
- `"2015-03-15"` -> gives a `date` because it matches `DQUOTE INT '-' INT '-' INT DQUOTE`

And I (tried?) to make sure that the parser tries to match a date *before* trying to match a string: `value: ...| date | string| ...`.

But when I use the `grun` utility (and my unit tests...), I can see that it categorizes the date as a string, like if it never bothered to check the date format.

[image: the ast]

Can you tell me why it is so?
I suspect there's a catch with the order in which I declare my grammar rules, but I tried some permutations and didn't get anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the failure to understand that the lexer runs to completion *before* any of the parser rules are effectively considered.

That means, the `STRING_LITERAL` lexer rule will consume all strings, dates included, and output just `STRING_LITERAL` tokens. The `date` and related parser subrules are never even considered by the parser.

Perhaps the minimal solution is to modify the `STRING_LITERAL` lexer rule to

```
STRING_LITERAL
    :  { notDateString() }? 
    ( QUOTE  .*? QUOTE
    | DQUOTE .*? DQUOTE
    )
    ;
```

The `notDateString` predicate requires native code to perform the essential disambiguation between date formats and other strings.

Another alternative is to promote the `STRING_LITERAL` rule entirely to the parser. Doable, but a bit messy depending on whether there is a need to preserve whitespaces within 'real' strings.

BTW, you may wish to add a [token stream dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197727/antlr-4-5-parser-error-during-runtime/29198883#29198883) to your standard series of unit tests.

Comment: I implemented another solution, which is to parse a date into the *string* rule. But I'll accept your solution as an alternative.