# ANTLR trying to create a lexer rule that goes up to, but not including, some symbols

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm using ANTLR4 to parse text adventure game dialogue files written in [Yarn](https://github.com/infiniteammoinc/Yarn), so mostly free form text and loads of island grammars, and for the most part things are going smoothly but I am having an issue excluding certain text inside the `Shortcut` mode (when presenting options for the player to choose from).

Basically I need to write a rule to match anything except `#`, newline or `<<`. When it hits a `<<` it needs to move into a new mode for handling expressions of various kinds or to just leave the current mode so that the `<<` will get picked up by the already existing rules.

A cut down version of my lexer (ignoring rules for expressions):

```
lexer grammar YarnLexer;

NEWLINE : ('\n') -> skip;

CMD : '<<' -> pushMode(Command);
SHORTCUT : '->' -> pushMode(Shortcut);

HASHTAG : '#' ;

LINE_GOBBLE : . -> more, pushMode(Line);

mode Line;
LINE : ~('\n'|'#')* -> popMode;

mode Shortcut ;
TEXT : CHAR+ -> popMode;
fragment CHAR : ~('#'|'\n'|'<');

mode Command ;
CMD_EXIT : '>>' -> popMode;

// RULES FOR OPERATORS/IDs/NUMBERS/KEYWORDS/etc
CMD_TEXT : ~('>')+ ;
```

And the parser grammar (again ignoring all the rules for expressions):

```
parser grammar YarnParser;

options { tokenVocab=YarnLexer; }

dialogue: statement+ EOF;

statement : line_statement | shortcut_statement | command_statement ;

hashtag : HASHTAG LINE ;

line_statement : LINE hashtag? ;

shortcut_statement : SHORTCUT TEXT command_statement? hashtag?;

command_statement : CMD expression CMD_EXIT;
expression : CMD_TEXT ;
```

I have tested the Command mode when it is by itself and everything inside there is working fine, but when I try to parse my example input:

```
Where should we go?
-> the park
-> the zoo
-> Peter's house <<if $metPeter == true >>

ok shall we take the bus?
-> :<
-> ok

<<set $daySpent = true>>
```

my issue is the line:

```
-> Peter's house <<if $metPeter == true >>
```

gets matched completely as TEXT and the CMD rules just gets ignored in favour by far longer TEXT.

My first thought was to add `<` to the set but then I can't have text like:

```
-> :<
```

which should be perfectly valid. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to include `<<` (and `>>`) into the list of "forbidden" tokens of the rule `CHAR`? Something like `fragment CHAR: ~('\n' | '#' | '<<' | '>>');`?

Comment: yeah that was the first thing I tried but turns out you can't have multi-char literals in sets in ANTLR.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single left angle bracket to the exclusion list creates a single corner case that is easily handled:

```
TEXT : CHAR+ ;
CMD  : '<<' -> pushMode(Command);
LAB  : '<'  -> type(TEXT) ;

fragment CHAR : ~('\n' | '#' | '<') ;
```

Comment: Ah this works, excellent! But there is an issue when I then try and embed all this into its own lexer mode. I was planning on using the TEXT to pop the mode, but that doesn't work when a line ends with a `<`

Comment: Why not use the guard pattern `'>>'` to terminate the mode? If this is not the entire answer, you will need to show your grammar and valid input use cases to get meaningful help.

Comment: very good point, updated my original question to show my grammar

Comment: The corner case (`LAB`) rule is missing. BTW, how do you know the line is being captured as `TEXT` and not `LINE`? Need to [dump the token stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197727/antlr-4-5-parser-error-during-runtime/29198883#29198883) to check.

Comment: Even with the `LAB` rule the problem still persists, detecting a `<` and emitting it as a `TEXT` still has the issue of not popping out of `Shortcut` mode.